# Acces : Select row with most recent date per product

Tags: ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I Have this table named Transaction :

[image: Transaction table]

And i am trying to make a SQL query on acess that would find, for each product, the most recent date associated. The results should look like this : (i want to see the quantity as well as the date and product name)

[image: Results]

Thanks

Comment: which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: i am using access 2007-2016, i'm not sure where i can check my mysql version

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite catch it. Are you using MS-Access or MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Consider filtering with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.date = (
    select max(t1.date)
    from transactions t1
    where t1.product = t.product
)
```

Comment: Hi,
After doing this, i get a few records for the same product. I want one date per product. (the most recent date)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `row_number` if you are using MySQL 8.0

```
select
    id,
    quantity,
    date
from
(
    select
        id,
        quantity,
        date,
        row_number() over (partition by product order by date desc) as rn
    from transaction
) subq
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `group` the rows by product while selecting the latest (`max`) date:

```
select t.product, t.quantity, t.date
from transaction t
inner join (
    select product, max(date) as MaxDate
    from transaction
    group by product
) tm on t.product = tm.product and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```